# Monitoring network usage according to IP address in Wireless network

Tags: networking, router, network-monitoring, wifi

Hiii,
I have an internet connection which is shared by 8 users via an D-Link N150 wireless router.
It is 1Mbps connection and we want that no one should download in excess when everyone is using the connection to surf.

For this, we want such a network monitor which gives the current download speed/bandwidth usage/upload speed of a particular user recognized by their IP address.

is there any software available for windows7 ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your N150 model is a DIR-600 revision B1 or B2, then [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) can provide you the functionality you're looking for.

Here's a how-to link from their wiki for that model: http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-600

Failing that, you'll need to introduce something in between the router and the uplink modem that will be able to handle whatever traffic monitoring you need, and possibly DHCP if you need it as well. A computer running Linux and [IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) should be sufficient, though the setup for that is way outside the scope of this question/answer

Comment: Hello, My router revision model in BX so it supports DD-WRT.